# How to get database backup from online server to offline server using PHP with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database-backups

```
//Assume Server 1
$conn = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","root","");

//Assume Server 2
$conn1 = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","root","");

//Server 1 database
mysql_select_db("db1",$conn);

//Server 2 database
mysql_select_db("db2",$conn1);

//Count number of rows from server 1 -> database -> table (tbl1)
$cnt_rw=mysql_query("select count(*) from db1.tbl1");
$cnt_n=mysql_fetch_array($cnt_rw);  

//Fetch and update row one by one
for($i=0;$i<($cnt_n['count(*)']);$i++)
{
    $one_row=mysql_query("select * from db1.tbl1 limit $i,1");
    while($one_val=mysql_fetch_array($one_row))
    {
        $one=$one_val['one'];
        $two=$one_val['two'];
        $three=$one_val['three'];
    }

    //Already exist means update else insert so am using replace query
    mysql_query("REPLACE INTO db2.tbl2(one,two,three)values('".$one."','".$two."','".$three."')");
    $one=$two=$three='';
}
```

This PHP code is working properly but take a long loading time. So I want a simple query or PHP/MySQL code or any idea to get backups from the online server to the offline server.

Online and offline database fields are same.

Answer (score 0):

Since using PHP might not be the best idea if you have large amount of data you could also use command line tools like [mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) to get a copy of the data and put it on your local machine with the mysql cli command.

Another option might be special tools like [sqlyog](https://www.webyog.com/product/sqlyog) which help you migrating data from one server to another.

Comment: cannot understand, please give any examples using PHP/MySQL.

Comment: you can use: `mysqldump -h LIVEHOST -u USERNAME -p DATABASE TABLE > dump.sql` and then reimport it on your local machine `mysql -h LOCALHOST -u USERNAME -p DATABASE < dump.sql`

Answer (score 0):

Common *admin solution* is to have cron script which [dumps](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html) whole db to file (ideally compressed to bz2) and then upload it via ftp, sftp, rsync to backup server.

Comment: cannot understand, please give any examples using PHP/MySQL.

Comment: this is not php solution. it is operation system solution.

Comment: `mysql --host=localhost --user=myname --password=mypass mydb
mysql -h localhost -u myname -pmypass mydb`
This is cmd prompt way. are you ask this way.

Comment: `mysqldump [options] > dump.sql  mysqldump [options] --result-file=dump.sql`  This is not working, any simple reference links available.

Comment: mysqldump [options] db_name > db_name.sql